# Javascript Function Understanding

Tags: javascript, html, loops, for-loop, for-in-loop

I am currently working on javascript function but these programe make me little bit confuse kindly please explain whole about the program given below, confusing towards for loop decrement.

```js
var socialMediaIcon = {
    facebook: "http://facebook.com/haseebjumani",
    Twitter: "http://twitter.com/haseebjumani",
    whatsapp: "http://whatsapp.com/",
    flickr: "http://flicker.com/haseebjumani"
}

var social = function() {
    var output = '<ul>',
    myList = document.querySelectorAll(".social-media");

    for (var key in arguments[0]) {
        output += '<li><a href="'+ socialMediaIcon[key] + '">' + 
        '<img src="images/' + key + '.png" alt="icon for' + key + '">' + '</a></li>';        
    }

    output += '</ul>';
   
        for(var i = myList.length - 1; i >= 0; i--){
        myList[i].innerHTML = output;
    };
    

}(socialMediaIcon);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <title>Social Media Icons</title>
</head>
<body>
    
    <nav class="social-media">g</nav>
    <h1>Welcome</h1>
    
    <p> lorem ipsum delor sit amit lorem ipsum delor sit amit lorem ipsum delor sit amit
        lorem ipsum delor sit amit lorem ipsum delor sit amit lorem ipsum delor sit amitlorem ipsum delor sit amit
        lorem ipsum delor sit amit lorem ipsum delor sit amit lorem ipsum delor sit amit lorem ipsum delor sit amit
    </p>
    <nav class="social-media"></nav>
    <script src="social.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: In this program you can see there is for loop in which i-- so my question is that when i code i-- the social media icons in nav showing 2 times, but when i code i++ its showed 1 times in the browser, even i put nav tag 2 times in the html editor, you can see above html and javascript code.

Comment: it loops trough the socialMediaIcons and creates the html ( first for loop ) than it adds that html to every socialmedia elem ( second for loop)

Comment: by the way, i dont get your codestructure, social will be empty...

Comment: because you don't have images folder i have images with facebook, Twitter, whatsapp, flickr with .png

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that `<nav class="social-media"></nav>` is used twice over here. So when you reach at this point of code `for(var i = myList.length - 1; i >= 0; i--)` it starts looking for **myList** in code which you have defined as `myList = document.querySelectorAll(".social-media");` If you have a close look in your for loop initialisation you will find follwing:

```
for(var i = myList.length - 1; i >= 0; i--)

First Iteration:

var i = myList.length - 1 /* 1 in this case */ 

now i >= 0  sets as True 

then you will see social icons on later .social-media as index in for loop is set as 1

Second Iteration:

var i = i-- /* here value of i is set to 0 */

now i >= 0 also sets to True

then you will seel social icons on first .social-media as index in for loop is set as 0
```

Other method if you want to use i++

Please initialisation your for loop as :

```
for(var i = 0; i <myList.length; i++)
```